# How do I replicate data from the Common Data Service to SQL Server on Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, common-data-service

I have data in Microsoft's Common Data Service (from Microsoft Dynamics for Talent). I can't use the Data Management Framework as the data in question is in entities that are not available through the DMF.

How do I replicate the data in the CDS back a SQL database?

What I've tried so far is to create a logic app (and flow, neither worked) that grabs data using the CDS connector and pushes it into an SQL database, but there are several problems with this:

1. It's a maintenance burden
2. It's extremely error tedious to add new tables, etc. I have written a somehwat horendous stored proc that tries to create a table based on the data given to it from the json-ified data from the flow, but this is very error prone.
3. It doesn't work at all, since the size of the data exceeds some kind of limitation in the SQL connector and I get spurious errors.

Rather than trying to push through with these issues, I'd rather ask whether there's a better way to achieve this. With the Data Management Framework in Dynamics it was simply a matter of scheduling these sync jobs, which worked pretty well. Is there something similar with CDS?

I've also tried looking at the Data Integration projects in Powerapps, but these only seem to allow me to get data *into* Powerapps/CDS, not back out...

Answer (score 1):

Common Data Service for Apps provides access to the data using the user interfaces or API, there is no direct access to the underlying database. This architecture has certain limitations when it comes to processing large volumes of data, for example for the purposes of data warehousing, reporting, or using Azure machine learning and analytics tools. Replicating CDS data using Extract, Transform, Load (ETL) tools is possible but inherently complex to maintain.

Data Export Service is a service made available on Microsoft AppSource that adds the ability to replicate Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement apps data to an Azure SQL Database store in a customer-owned Azure subscription.

Note: The Data Export Service requires Dynamics 365 for Customer Engagement apps subscription, it is not available on Common Data Service for Apps plans.